# Download image from servlet by button click i GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I used that code to create the servlet: [How to get image with servlet and display it using GWT Image class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491025/how-to-get-image-with-servlet-and-display-it-using-gwt-image-class)
And I used that code to create the button: [How to download a file via a button click i GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684666/how-to-download-a-file-via-a-button-click-i-gwt)
The mapping to the servlet in my web.xml file is like that:
    `<servlet-mapping>`
       `<servlet-name>MyImageServlet</servlet-name>`
       `<url-pattern>*.images</url-pattern>`
    `</servlet-mapping>`

I give the name of the file with a get parameter "name".
The probleme is, when I click on the button, the files name is always "servlet.images".

How can I do to rename the image with the right name when the user wants to download the image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In servlet.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                     "attachment;filename=downloadname.txt");
```